# In nodejs how to get the path in the callback of fs.readfile

Tags: node.js

I am using chokidar watcher to watch a directory. I want the path name in the fs.readFile 's callback. If I write the code as follows:

```
watcher.on('add', path => {
            var log = console.log.bind(console);
            log(`File ${path} has been added`);
            fs.readFile(path,'utf-8', function(err, data,path) {
log(`File ${path} has been read`);
......
......
```

The following  is the output:

> File test1.txt has been added
>
> File undefined has been read

How can I get the value of path in the fs.readfile callback

Comment: Drop the `path` parameter from the `fs.readFile()` callback and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`fs.readFile(path,'utf-8', callback..`, here callback only contains two arguments, `1-error , 2-data`. Values for error and data are passed to the respective arguments. (Note first one always for error and the other for data).

You are adding a third argument to this callback, which will never contain any value, so you see that `undefined` because `fs` module never populates any other argument except for `error` and `data`. So, first remove this from the callback arguments  and your callback should look like

```
 fs.readFile(path,'utf-8', function(err, data) {..
```

Now you should see the file name printed in console.

Moreover, you can always use `path` module of `nodejs` and

```
path.basename('pathToFile')
```

will return the name of the file in the path you specify as an argument